# Is SAML 2.0 provides Error Codes?

Tags: saml-2.0

Is Saml 2.0 provides error code? 
Is there any list of SAML 2.0 error codes?
I have searched a lot but I am not able to find it out.

Answer (score 0):

SAML protocol defines error states and appropriate codes based on a specific sequence of steps (Profile in SAML protocol parlance)

Start here: http://identitymeme.org/doc/draft-hodges-learning-saml-00.html . The links to specification docs in this document point to originally released document versions and they're still good but there have been some minor changes since 2005 (errata). The latest docs are available from https://wiki.oasis-open.org/security/FrontPage

Take a look at Core and Profiles specifications. The Core specification defines elements Status, StatusCode, StatusMessage and StatusDetail. There's a list of error codes documented for Status element.

The Profiles specification defines how and when error conditions are encountered and rendered in requests/responses.